# I want to make coffee in Minecraft 1.15.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok so I want to give a honey bottle when drunk gives you speed and jump boost for 5 minutes. How could I do this?

Comment: I recommend reading the [tour] to understand what should be included in questions on this website.

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 1):

Using [this generator](https://minecraft.tools/en/potion.php), you can make your own custom potions with whatever effects you like. It might not be a honey bottle, but it’s as close as it gets as far as I know. Hope this helps!